# How can I prevent users from aborting a Pipeline Input Step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In the Input step, I want only users with sufficient permissions to be able to do it. But users with build permission can do it

I just searched the internet and didn't get any answer for my case

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this by removing the Cancel permission for a user or a group of users from a given Job. The following is with `Matrix-based security`.

[image]

Take a look at this Document as well.

https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/cloudbees-jenkins-enterprise/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-aborting-a-pipeline-input-step-using-rbac